# Executing dynamic gradle task with gradle 6

Tags: java, gradle

We moved from gradle 4 to 6 directly. In one of our methods, we create a task and were executing it earlier.

```
def myCopy(src, dest, rules) {
    //check some biz logic with rules
    Copy cc = task("cc${dest}",type:Copy)
    cc.from src
    cc.into dest
    //this worked in gradle 4. With gradle 6 it throws an error:Could not find method execute() for arguments
    cc.execute()
}

task doCopy {
    doLast {
        myCopy('resources', 'newResources', [])
    }
}
```

With gradle 6, we get this error: > Could not find method execute() for arguments.

We know execute has been removed, so we tried executing it with finalizedBy:

```
task noop {
    doLast {
        println "Noop..."
    }
}

def myCopy(src, dest, rules) {
    //check some biz logic with rules
    Copy cc = task("cc${dest}",type:Copy)
    cc.from src
    cc.into dest
    //this worked in gradle 4. With gradle 6 it throws an error:Could not find method execute() for arguments
    tasks.getByName("noop").finalizedBy "cc${dest}"
}

task doCopy {
    doLast {
        myCopy('resources', 'newResources', [])
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work either. Any pointers will be great. Thank you!

Comment: You can't create new tasks at execution time, and you also can't execute them directly yourself. When should your copy task run compared to the other tasks you have?

Comment: You can create tasks but can't execute them. Anyways, we've refactored the code to create a method and call that method from myCopy. I'll reply it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling a task from a method is not possible as execute() method has been removed. We ended up writing java code to copy the contents instead of using copy task.

```
def myCopy(sourceFolder, destinationFolder, rules){
    //check some biz logic with rules
    if (sourceFolder.isDirectory())  {
        if (!destinationFolder.exists()) {
            destinationFolder.mkdir();
        }
        String[] files = sourceFolder.list();

        for (String file : files) {
            File srcFile = new File(sourceFolder, file);
            File destFile = new File(destinationFolder, file);
            myCopy(srcFile, destFile, rules);
        }
    }
    else {
        Files.copy(sourceFolder.toPath(), destinationFolder.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
}

task doCopy {
    myCopy(new File("./src/sub/"), new File("./newSrc2"), [])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The usage smell is that you create a task, `doCopy`, which invokes a method which in turn creates a copy task.
Why don't you simply create the copy task initially?

```
task doCopy(type: Copy) {
    from 'resources'
    into 'newResources'
}
```

In Gradle 6.0, you cannot execute a task that is not part of the task graph after Gradle has finished evaluating your projects.

If what you are after in your project is a way to generalise task creation based on external parameters, have a look at [task rules](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:task_rules).

Comment: The reason myCopy was created was to apply some business logic and then copy. And this method is being called from multiple other methods. Anyways, we've refactored the code to create a method and call that method from myCopy. I'll reply it as an answer below.